# Is there an ability to get some event when Angular 2+ component's DOM elements get rendered in browser?

Tags: angular

I have an Angular parent component the includes 1000+ DOM nodes (rendered by 2 ngFor cycles, like 2D table).
Each DOM node is an Angular component.
Component's styles and displayed values get applied to them via @Input properties. These input properties provides data synchronously, no need to wait until them init.

Theoretically all 1000+ components initialization should happen fast (including styles and values passing) and should be finished till AfterViewInit fires. But in fact, there is a time lag between AfterViewInit hook is fired and DOM elements gets visible in browser. The lag is significant for me (500 - 1000ms).

So, my question is: can we somehow know when exactly all DOM nodes will get visible in browser with their styles and values.

Tried to use AfterViewInit hook and AfterViewChecked, but it is not exactly what I need.

Comment: Which AfterViewInit need so long time? The main components? Or of the childs?

Comment: code scheduled via setTimeout(() => ..., 0) would be run after rendering if you really need it. afterViewInit runs after angular has created all the dom nodes that would be displayed, but it seems it takes a while for browser to render all of those nodes

Comment: You can subscribe to ViewChildren changes. This should inform you when all of the ViewChildren have completed their lifecycles. I've used that technique in the past and it's more reliable than setting timeouts, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to the "changes" observable of ViewChildren in AfterviewInit. This should inform you after all of the ViewChildren have run through their lifecycles and rendering is complete.

Example:

```js
// your.component.ts
import { AfterViewInit, Component, QueryList, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';
import { YourChildComponent } from 'your-module';

@Component({ ... })
export class YourComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChildren(YourChildComponent)
  yourChildComponents: QueryList<YourChildComponent>;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.yourChildComponents
        .changes
        .subscribe(() => {
          // Your code here
        });
  }

}
```

Of course, you'd want to keep a reference to the subscription so you can unsubscribe and don't get memory leaks.

Comment: Tried this approach. The "changes" do not emit values in my case. Even I subscribe to it inside ViewChildren setter. Maybe it happens because "YourComponent" is detached from change detection.
However, your solution looks good. I think it will work in more common cases than my.

Comment: Are you sure your selector is correct? The `changes` subscription will always fire when the ViewChildren are rendered.